# React Datepicker поплыли стрелочки переключения месяцев

Tags: reactjs

[image: Календарь]

```
import cx from 'classnames';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
            <DatePicker
              name="effectiveDate"
              className={cx(styles.formInput, styles.datePicker)}
              onChange={value => setFieldValue('effectiveDate', value)}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
              showYearDropdown
              selected={values.effectiveDate}
              placeholderText="yyyy/mm/dd"
              autoComplete="off"
            />
    
css:
  .formInput {
    color: #40475d;
    padding-left: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e7ed;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .datePicker {
    max-width: 170px;
    background: #fff;
  }
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы эти стрелочки стояли нормально по бокам?

Comment: а код привести как и что Вы имортируете и используете

Comment: Прошу прощения, добавил.

Comment: импорты где? И как нам понять, что используется здесь `className={cx(styles.formInput, styles.datePicker)}`?

Comment: добавил css и импорты

Comment: где-то должен еще импортироваться `react-datepicker.css`